# Mapping Object Stream hibernate Java EE

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, mapping

I have a mapping problem while trying to map input and output streams into my database . i have tried to make the input streams as Blob but it didn't work . 
i need to make simple chat , and so the client can send and receive files . so that's why i need them to be in the database . I have Also tried to just store the Content of the file but also didn't work .

I have got the exception below :

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type
>   for: java.io.ObjectInputStream, at table: User, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ois)]"}}

```
      @Entity

 public class User implements Serializable {
 private Integer id;
 private Socket sock;
private boolean isConnected;
private ObjectInputStream ois;
private ObjectOutputStream oos;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Socket getSock() {
    return sock;
}

public void setSock(Socket sock) {
    this.sock = sock;
}

public boolean isConnected() {
    return isConnected;
}

public void setConnected(boolean isConnected) {
    this.isConnected = isConnected;
}

public  ObjectInputStream getOis() {
    return ois;
}

public void setOis(ObjectInputStream ois) {
    this.ois = ois;
}

public ObjectOutputStream getOos() {
    return oos;
}

public void setOos(ObjectOutputStream oos) {
    this.oos = oos;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type of field is Blob, you could use a byte array, something like this:

```
@Column(name="ois")
private byte[] ois;

public byte[] getOis() {
    return ois;
}

public void setOis(byte[] ois) {
    this.ois = ois;
}
```

You just need to transform a file to byte array, after that you can store it on your database using Hibernate, for instance:

```
File file = new File("C:\\my_file.txt");
byte[] byteFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

try {
  FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
  fileInputStream.read(byteFile);
  fileInputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  //Handle the error
}
```

I hope this information helps you.